# Conditional writing to xlsx

Tags: python, pandas

Folks,

I'm currently working with a huge excel sheet, python 3.7.1 and pandas 0.23.4.
My task is to write to cells based on conditional matching. Something like this:

```
val = lincoln@gmx.net
if val in Cell_3A:
    write something to Cell_3B
```

To make a complete example, let's say the following is my dataframe:

```
    Email               Protection
1   lincoln@gmail.net
2   obama@gmail.net
3   trump@gmail.net
4   franklin@gmail.net
```

I know want to write down that all of the emails are protected, except for the email in row 3. So the finished dataframe should look like this:

```
    Email               Protection
1   lincoln@gmail.net   on
2   obama@gmail.net     on
3   trump@gmail.net     off
4   franklin@gmail.net  on
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain this any further, anky_91?

Comment: Mowgli check ans. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

filter the `Protection` column where the email is not `'trump@gmail.net'` and assign them 'on' and vice versa.

```
df.loc[df['Email']!='trump@gmail.net', 'Protection']='on'
df.loc[df['Email']=='trump@gmail.net', 'Protection']='off'
```

using `np.where`:

```
df['Protection'] = np.where((df['Email']!='trump@gmail.net'),'on','off')
```

or:

```
df['Protection'] = np.where((df['Email']=='trump@gmail.net'),'off','on')
```

Comment: anky_91, i was just about  to post np.where solution you beated me fast :-) +1 , easiest and fater as well.

Comment: ha ha. :D yeah, thought to post this since this is faster. :)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve my problem, BUT: 

" A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

We're getting a SettingWithCopyWarning here!

Comment: Yes, I'm using the numpy-solution. I changed the method of accessing to the suggested .iloc-method, but I keep getting the same 'SettingWithCopyWarning'-Error.

Comment: even this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033471/getting-settingwithcopywarning-warning-even-after-using-loc-in-pandas

Comment: Thanks! Best fucking served, sir.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) helped me a lot.Took some time, but found out that I was declaring slices of my dataframe the wrong way for this situation.

Comment: oops, solution is wrong, need change `df['Protection'][df['Email']!='trump@gmail.net']` to `df.loc[df['Email']!='trump@gmail.net', 'Protection']` and similar for second row

Comment: @jezrael yes, i trusted the np.where solution more , thank you, changed. Bad use of slicers. :p

Comment: @anky_91 - Ya, it is common mistake if someone start working with pandas, +1

Answer (score 3):

Just another Solution around based on if  and else condition:

**DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
                Email Protection
0   lincoln@gmail.net
1     obama@gmail.net
2     trump@gmail.net
3  franklin@gmail.net
```

**Result:**

```
>>> df['Protection'] = ['On' if x !="trump@gmail.net"  else 'Off' for x in df['Email']]
 # df['Protection'] = ['Off' if x =="trump@gmail.net"  else 'On' for x in df['Email']]
>>> df
                Email Protection
0   lincoln@gmail.net         On
1     obama@gmail.net         On
2     trump@gmail.net        Off
3  franklin@gmail.net         On
```